# Why does my locator isn't working together?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-rc

These two lines are working independently. If I commented one and run it works. But it is not working together.

line1:`driver.findElement(By.id("MemberNo")).sendKeys("1");`

line2:`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"VoucherNo\"]")).sendKeys("20201001");`

Getting no Exception. UI Scenario:[image]

Advise and suggestions as I am new to selenium java.

Comment: The question is un-clear. If you click the same locator twice like the way you describe it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:

- Check if the xpath is proper. Since you said its working independently, I assume its correct.
- Generally if we use double quotes everywhere you may get into issue. Try using the combination of single or double quotes. For the second xpath you may try something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='VoucherNo']")).sendKeys("20201001");`
- Sometimes there needs to be some time gap required while working on multiple elements in the same form. Try putting a wait condition between those two statements and execute.

Since both of the lines are performing action on different UI elements and as they are working independently, I don't see a possible scenario of why they wont work combinely.